# C++ Function pointer issues

Tags: c++, sockets, function-pointers

I want to send a function pointer as a parameter for another function, but my function refuses to accept member functions of a class as a parameter. I have tried send a nonmember function and a member function as a parameter and it only compiles when I use nonmember functions. I need to send a member function so I have access to variables.

Here is the function call that works:

```
daSocket->beginReceive(chuckTesta, fakePayload);
```

here is the header for chuckTesta():

```
void chuckTesta(std::string *message, ssError& e, void *payload)
```

The compiler is completely silent...

Here is the function call that DOES NOT works:

```
daSocket->beginReceive(client::passwordAttemptCallback, fakePayload);
```

here is the header for client::passwordAttemptCallback():

```
void client::passwordAttemptCallback(std::string *message, ssError& e, void *payload)
```

the compiler says:

```
client2.cpp: In member function ‘void client::enterPassword()’:
client2.cpp:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘StringSocket::beginReceive(<unresolved overloaded function type>, void*&)’
../StringSocket/StringSocket.h:53: note: candidates are: void StringSocket::beginReceive(StringSocket::receiveCallback, void*)
```

here is header for StringSocket::beginReceive():

```
void beginReceive(receiveCallback callBack, void* payload);
```

where a receiveCallback is:

```
typedef boost::function<void (string *message, ssError& e, void *payload) > receiveCallback;
```

Why does this work with nonmember functions but fail with member functions?

Comment: free function and member function have different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send member function pointers. One way to get the same result is, creating a non-member function that takes, all the member function's parameters and a reference to that class's object and then call that member function on that object.

i.e.

```
class A{
 void func(int a, int b){
 }
 static void nonMemberFunc(A * a, int b, int c){
   a -> func(b, c)
 }
}
```

Now, pass nonMemberFunc and `this` as a pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Because (non-static) member functions and non-member functions are entirely different beasts.  A non-static member function expects an extra `this` parameter; it is implicit, but the `boost::function` object still needs to pass it somehow.  What you could construct is a

```
boost::function<void (client*, string *message, ssError& e, void *payload)>
```

which would then work just fine.  However, what you probably really want is to use Boost.Bind and construct your `boost::function` like this:

```
bind(&client::passwordAttemptCallBack, &myClient, _1)
```

which will make `&myClient` be passed for that place.